# Are these matrices similar

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B \in M_n$ and let $A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
B & C \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \in M_{n+m}$
such that $Rank([B \space \space C]) = Rank(B)$. Show that $A$ is similar to $B \oplus 0_m$

So since we have the rank condition it seems that $A$ can be reduced to 
$\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ via row and column operations. However I don't see how they necessarily need to be similar. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each column of $C$ must be a linear combination of the columns of $B$.  That says $C = BS$ (where the $k$'th column of $S$ gives the coefficients for writing the $k$'th column of $C$ as a linear combination of the columns of $B$).  Then

$$ \pmatrix{B & C\cr 0 & 0\cr} = \pmatrix{B & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} \pmatrix{I & S\cr 0 & I\cr}
= \pmatrix{I & -S\cr 0 & I\cr} \pmatrix{B & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} \pmatrix{I & S\cr 0 & I\cr}$$
where $$\pmatrix{I & -S\cr 0 & I\cr} = \pmatrix{I & S\cr 0 & I\cr}^{-1}$$